# Is it possible to add calculated range to excel dataset in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

We need to move data from Excel (in Sharepoint) to SqlDB in Azure Data Factory.

We have an excel where row amount increase now and then, but last row is Total which we don't want to take along. Excel has data in A-L columns and there are some other data in N-> columns which also we don't want to take.
[Excel looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItZDH.png)

At the moment we have hard-coded range A1:L9999, but that takes also the 'Total' row.
[Dataset looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzDc.png)

We would like to have range which checks in which row has A? = 'Total' and then create range A1:L? It looks like range needs to be in exact format, because when we tried like '@{concat('A1:L','=MATCH("Total",A:A,0)')}' we got error:

ErrorCode=ExcelInvalidCellRange,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid excel cell range '@{concat('A1:L','=MATCH("Total",A:A,0)')}' with error 'Input string was not in a correct format.'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,

Any ideas?

My first question, sorry about possibly missing details.

EDIT: We probably need this same solution to fit to multiple excels with same or different logics in range (or no range at all).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add calculated range to excel dataset in Azure Data Factory?

As per your information you have last row in your file is **Total** and  you want to get that row number and pass the value dynamically in range.

**To achieve this follow below steps:**

- You need to first lookup the file and **it will give you count of the rows in file**. you will get output something like below if you have not selected first row as header you will get count as **9** and if you selected first row as header you will get **8** count.
  [image]
- Then pass this count in range of copy activity by subtracting 1 from it as you don't want las row which has Total to do this create dataset parameter foe `lastrange`
  [image]
  pass this parameter in range as `@{concat('A1:L',dataset().lastrange)}`
  [image]
  The pass the lookup count by subtracting 1 from it with expression `@sub(int(activity('Lookup1').output.count),1)`
  [image]

**Output and data preview for above:**
[image]

Comment: Hey @pratik, there are limitations w.r.t lookup activity because of which this might not work in all cases just a head up :)

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add, that there might be more than one excel which might or might not have same problem, but all of them would be nice to loop in same For Each. That maybe can be handled with variable and if:s or so.
But the header row is problem with lookup. We want to have 'First row as header' tapped and Look up doesn't like that :/. Any tips for that?